# Changing the values of a chosen element in an one dimentional array in JAVA program

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, methods

Here is my program which stores grades (elements) into a Gradebook (array)
[image]

I'm basically trying to allow the user to be able to change whichever grade the (element) they want in the Gradebook(array) as many times as they would like (loop basically). I've given the user the option to enter the index (which should start from 1 rather 0, in order to avoid confusion for the user) but after that step I'm stuck. I'm not sure how to search for the element in the array and then ask the user to replace it...

Here is my code so far:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NewGradeBook {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Ask user to enter the amount of grades
        int grades = NumberReader.readPositiveInt(input, "Please enter the number of grades: ",
                "Error: Invalid data entered");

        int numOfGrades = grades;

        double[] mogrades = new double[numOfGrades];

        for (int i = 0; i < mogrades.length; i++) {

            //Allows user to enter each individual grade
            System.out.println("Enter grade (limit to two decimal places)" + (i + 1) + ": ");

            //Stores grades in array
            mogrades[i] = NumberReader.readPositiveDouble(input, "Enter grade " + (i+1) + " :", "Invalid data entered");

        }

        System.out.println("The Grade book contains: ");

        printArray(mogrades);

        System.out.println("___________________________");

        //Ask user if what grade they would like to change
        int index = NumberReader.readPositiveInt(input,
                "Enter the index of the grade to be changed: (1 to " + grades + ") : ", "Invalid index input");

    }

    public static void printArray(double[] mogrades) {

        for (int i = 0; i < mogrades.length; i++) {

            System.out.print("Grade " + (i + 1) + " is: " + mogrades[i] + ", ");

        }

    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Ugh. Is it necessary to explain your whole program? Surely you are stuck on a specific thing and can narrow it down to that.

Comment: Hmmm I guess I should wait a bit longer and maybe delete this question and try to repost without going into too much detail.

Comment: Editing it is fine. It will perhaps be put on hold and you will have an opportunity to edit it before it gets closed. I wouldn't suggest deleting and reposting.

Comment: @Coco see my answer before you repost. I think it should be helpful.

Comment: Well, I downsized it a bit, hopefully it'll help those viewing. Thanks for the tip. :)

Answer (score 0):

The structure should be similar to this:

```
 System.out.println("___________________________");

 System.out.println("Make changes? Enter Y or N");
 String makeChanges = System.console().readLine();
 while (makeChanges.equals("Y")) {
  //Ask user if what grade they would like to change
  int index = NumberReader.readPositiveInt(input,
   "Enter the index of the grade to be changed: (1 to " + grades + ") : ", "Invalid index input");

  System.out.println("Enter grade (limit to two decimal places)" + index + ": ");
  //offset the index by one
  mogrades[index - 1] = NumberReader.readPositiveDouble(input, "Enter grade " + index + " :", "Invalid data entered");

  System.out.println("Make changes? Enter Y or N");
  makeChanges = System.console().readLine();
 }
}
```

You want to continue looping while they still want to make changes.

Comment: I tried implementing your code but there's an error referring to the variable 'i' in (i+1) seems it's not declared? Idk should I try declaring it? I'll give it a go.

Comment: Not sure what you mean but I ended up initializing i by writing

int i;           

outside of the for-loop which got rid of the errors but unfortunetally, after running the program, it aske for "Make changes? Enter Y or N" but an error print stating 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at NewGradeBook.main(NewGradeBook.java:37)

Comment: i edited my answer to remove references to i. it should reference the index in your array the user is currently changing, so i changed it to reflect that.

Comment: Tried changing it up to reference the index but still the when run it ends with these lines...

_Make changes? Enter Y or N_
**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at NewGradeBook.main(NewGradeBook.java:36)**

Last two lines describing the errors... :/

Comment: Just need to probably replace System.console().readLine() with whatever method you are using to read a string from the user.

Comment: Looks like I didn't create a method to read strings. I'll go ahead and do that and see it works. I'll get back to ya. Thanks for the help so far ^^